# odoo 9 how to add relational field to pivot view?

Tags: odoo, pivot, odoo-9, one2many

I'm customizing Project's pivot view to show timesheet description along with task's name.

here is my code below but when I click pivot view it shows an error

```
<!-- Insert Project Issue Pivot Field -->
<record id="project_task_custom_pivot" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">project.task.custom.pivot</field>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_project_task_pivot"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="stage_id" position="after">
            <field name="name" type="row"/>
            <field name="timesheet_ids" type="row"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Error below

```
assert groupby_def and groupby_def._classic_write, "Fields in 'groupby' must be regular database-persisted fields (no function or related fields), or function fields with store=True"
```

**Edit**

I re-defined the field "timesheet_ids" as @George Daramouskas mentioned.

```
timesheet_ids = fields.One2many('account.analytic.line', 'task_id', string="Timesheetss", store=True)
```

But It didn't work.
So I took a look at the source code in [Odoo Source](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/fields.py#L1860)

The function "One2many" has no such a parameter.

I guess the Store=True is for only regular field not related field.

Is there any other solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create your field with the attribute `store=True` in the constructor so that the field is stored in the database.

Comment: Do you mean override the field"timesheet_ids"?

Comment: Yes, re-defined it with a `store=True` or another appropriate condition so that the field is always up to date.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I edited the original question above.